# Apache Mina: Get the user's username upon receiving a command

Tags: ssh, sshd, mina, access-rights

Using Apache Mina, I'm trying to allow certain users to run certain custom SSH commands. But I can't figure out how to get the username or any sort of information about the user in a `CommandFactory`.

Right now, my server configuration looks like this:

```
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new SshPasswordAuthenticator());
sshd.setPort(localServerPort);
sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
sshd.setShellFactory(new SshShellFactory());
sshd.setSessionFactory(new SshSessionFactory());
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("my.pem").getAbsolutePath()));
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(path.getAbsolutePath()));
List<NamedFactory<Command>> namedFactoryList = new ArrayList<>();
namedFactoryList.add(new SftpSubsystem.Factory());
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(namedFactoryList);
```

And this is what my `SshShellFactory` class looks like:

```
import org.apache.sshd.common.Factory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.Command;
import org.apache.sshd.server.CommandFactory;


public class SshShellFactory implements CommandFactory, Factory<Command> {

    @Override
    public Command createCommand(String command) {
        return new SshSessionCommandWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public Command create() {
        return createCommand("none");
    }
}
```

Where `ServerVariables` stores variables related to my software, `SshSessionCommandWriter` does I/O operations on the streams and `SshCommandManager` interprets commands read in `SshSessionCommandWriter` and returns a value to the client.

If I could find a way to somehow get the username of the user running the command, It would be perfect for my use case. I currently have this information in `SshSessionFactory` and `SshPasswordAuthenticator`, but not in `SshShellFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `SshSessionCommandWriter` object that I created must implement the `Command` interface. This command interface has the method `public void start(Environment env)` in its contracts. It turns out the username is stored inside the environment variables:

```
public class SshSessionCommandWriter implements Command, Runnable {

    @Override
    public void start(Environment env) throws IOException {
        String username = env.getEnv().get(Environment.ENV_USER);
    }
}
```